# MSSQL Efficient return from list of Monthly Log Tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, subquery

I am re-writing a report (in classic-asp) which connects to MSSQL and reports users usage.

I have multiple "Log" tables for each month since we started logging, anytime a user logs in to the system, they add a log with the Type of "successful login".

In my report I am trying to return the latest login based on a user ID.

Currently, I am using ASP to create a loop of all of the log tables in the database, to "union all", and querying the unioned tables for the userid and action of "successful login". This takes approximately 30 minutes to complete, since the logs have grown so large.

If I limit the search to the last 3 months tables, this comes down to somewhere in the region of 5 minutes (there are 14k+ users in the database, and the report offers much more information than their last login, using SQL Execution plan manager, I have found that searching these 40+ log tables is the bottleneck.

I have been considering that using If-Else statements in the SQL might be a way to *only* search multiple tables, should a row not be found, but i'm struggling to identify the logic, and as always, there is likely to be a much more efficient method of finding the results I have not even considered.

using the last 3 Months

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Top 1 LastLogin FROM (SELECT Top 1 Date As LastLogin FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M7 WHERE Y2020M7.UserID = Project_Users.UserID AND Type = 'Successful Login' ORDER BY Date Desc UNION ALL SELECT Top 1 Date As LastLogin FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M6 WHERE Y2020M6.UserID = Project_Users.UserID AND Type = 'Successful Login' ORDER BY Date Desc UNION ALL SELECT Top 1 Date As LastLogin FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M5 WHERE Y2020M5.UserID = Project_Users.UserID AND Type = 'Successful Login' ORDER BY Date Desc UNION ALL SELECT Top 1 Date As LastLogin FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M4 WHERE Y2020M4.UserID = Project_Users.UserID AND Type = 'Successful Login' ORDER BY Date Desc) As Tbl Order BY LastLogin Desc) As LastLogin FROM Project_Users ORDER BY Name
```

There are a number of databases with the title format of Y2020M1, Y2020M2, Y2020M3, Y2020M4 etc...

How can I avoid searching the earlier logs if I find a result in the later logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the performance you can get rid of the subquery in the select statement.
Doing a subquery in a select with a where clause that is dependent on the outer select means SQL server will evaluate this row by row.

**Option 1** Using GROUP BY with union and join

```
SELECT Name
    , logins.LastLogin
FROM Project_Users pu
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UserId , MAX(LastLogin) LastLogin
        FROM (
            SELECT Y2020M7.UserID, DATE AS LastLogin
            FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M7
            WHERE Type = 'Successful Login'
            GROUP BY Y2020M7.UserID
            ORDER BY DATE DESC
            
            UNION ALL
            
            SELECT Y2020M6.UserID, DATE AS LastLogin
            FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M6
            WHERE Type = 'Successful Login'
            GROUP BY Y2020M6.UserID
            ORDER BY DATE DESC
            -- TODO other tables
            
            ) AS Tbl
        GROUP BY UserId
) logins on logins.UserId = pu.UserID
ORDER BY Name
```

**Option 2**
Using multiple joins and Max.

```
SELECT Name
    , (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (loginsY2020M7.Date), (loginsY2020M6.loginsY2020M6),...) AS value(v)) as [LastLogin]
FROM Project_Users pu
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Y2020M7.UserID , MAX(DATE) Date
    FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M7
    WHERE  Type = 'Successful Login'
    GROUP BY Y2020M7.UserID
) loginsY2020M7 on loginsY2020M7.UserId = pu.UserId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Y2020M6.UserID , MAX(DATE) Date
    FROM PARProjectLogs.dbo.Y2020M6
    WHERE  Type = 'Successful Login'
    GROUP BY Y2020M6.UserID
) loginsY2020M6 on loginsY2020M6.UserId = pu.UserId
-- TODO all other table in same way
ORDER BY Name
```

By using the `join` and `group by` SQL server can optimize and execute on a set instead of on the row level like your example.

Comment: Thanks for that, those are 2 very elegant solutions to my problem within this nested query of multiple tables.

I'm not sure why I hadn't considered Joining the results of the unioned tables but what you say makes perfect sense, if they're joined it only has to compile the million or so lines of log files into one table that is joined once, rather than for every line. Instantly saving billions of cycles.